# 70s or 80s TV Movie about an identical Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

It was a TV sci-fi movie or short episode (maybe like *The Twilight Zone* series), colored.

An astronaut goes to a planet (may be Jupiter or one of its moons) and land. It looks identical to Earth except that no one can see him. He visits his house and only the dog can sense/see him.

As far as I can remember he runs back to his rocket to leave.

**Ruled out:**

- "The Martian Chronicles"
- Twilight Zone episode "The Parallel"
- "Doppelganger" aka "Journey to the far side of the Sun"

Comment: Could be https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080242/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl - The Martian Chronicles TV Mini series from 1980?

Comment: @Alith Thanks for the reply. But that was not what I was looking for.

Comment: What you describe seems to contain elements of a Twilight Zone episode [The Parallel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734670/?ref_=ttep_ep11) and a Gerry Anderson movie ["Doppelganger" aka "Journey to the far side of the Sun"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger_(1969_film)), although the specific details you described don't fully align with either of them.

Comment: @Aanthony X Thanks for the reply. yeap I found them too, but not exactly what I was looking for. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Time Warp](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808502/), a TV movie from 1981 with Adam West.

> After a long space journey, an astronaut returns home to his family--only to discover that he has somehow gone through a "time warp" and is now one year into the future, rendering him invisible to all those around him.

However, **his dog (and a couple of parrots) do sense him.**

The movie is currently [available on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL03llOtYFs), and here's the trailer:

Comment: Thanks Walt, that seems like the one!. Boy that removed a big nagging thorn from my childhood memory. Though this is a full length movie, I remember watching only about an hour, may it was broken in to 2 parts for TV. The only mismatch is that the rocket I remembered was like a "Saturn V" type, where as this one is more like a "shuttle". But must be my mind mixing stuff up. Thanks again!.